# Sending Image file data from C# windows application to WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf

I am working on a C# windows application and trying to send the byte[] of image file to a WCF service. Below is my code in windows application.

```
private bool SaveVisitorPhoto()
{
byte[] visitorPhotoByte;
using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
{

    visitorPhotoByte = ImageUtility.ImageToByte(picVisitorPhoto.Image, ImageFormat.Png);
    string url = webServiceURL + "SaveVisitorPhoto/" + VisitPIN;
    webClient.UploadData(url, visitorPhotoByte);
    return true;
}}

[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "SaveVisitorPhoto/{visitPIN}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]bool SaveVisitorPhoto(string visitPIN);
```

Now I am not sure how to get the byte[] data in WCF service, or is there any other way to achieve this.

I saw many atricles, but I could not find any working sample to send Image data to WCF service. Let me know, if anyone has worked on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following sample method to receive the bytes

```
    public void UploadData(string URL,byte[] byteArrayIn)
    {
       ----------
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, "UploadData" is a method of "WebClient" object. But I was expecting the byte[] data in "SaveVisitorPhoto" method.

Comment: I tried to pass the content as base64 string in WebClient Headers. But I am getting Bad request error. I have set the maxStringContentLength="2147483647" in config file under "bindings" section. No luck. But I am able to successfully get other header values in WCF Service side, if I don't pass the base64 string data.